# what is desktop environment and where is placed in linux architecture

Tags: desktop-environments, architecture

What is the role of the **desktop environment** in the architecture of a Linux-based operating system like Ubuntu?

Can anyone explain what a desktop environment is and how it relates to other components of the system?

Comment: This isn't strictly specific about Ubuntu and I'm sure it has been answered here [Unix & Linux StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @UriHerrera We allow lots of questions that also apply to other Unix-like operating systems. Furthermore, a good answer to this question could be posted, that addresses Ubuntu-specific aspects of the question. (For instance, it would be great to have an answer that explains what a desktop environment is *and how Unity is not, contrary to what many people seem to believe, a desktop environment*).

Comment: We could answer a question like this on [unix.se], but **read the Wikipedia article first**. IF you still have questions **AFTER READING THE WIKIPEDIA ARTICLE**, feel free to ask them on U&L.

Comment: sorry i forget linux unix stack exchange site....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nutshell,

1. The Linux Kernel runs on the hardware. (init and other essential processes
   start)
2. After essential processes are up and running, Kernel runs X-server
   (another set of software).
3. Desktop environment such as Gnome, KDE, DWM runs using the
   facilities provided by the X.

Everything works in layered fashion.